# Python - Beautiful Soup - delete values before <br> tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have data within a tag separated with a br, and I'm trying to figure out how I can delete all the values before the br tag and having difficulty.

Here is an example of what my data looks like:

```html
<td>
  ValueToBeDeleted
  <br>
  <br/> ValueToKeep
</td>
```

So I am trying to keep 'ValueToKeep' and get rid of the previous value within the TD tag for the data I'm working on. Also, my data file has hundreds of these TD tags that I need to clean up, so I'm searching for an iterative solution as well. Any ideas?

Comment: You can maybe do it by using a regex pattern somthing like this might work ^\<br\/\>(.*)
Notice that what you are looking for will be in the first group

Answer (score 1):

MayBe:

```
text = text.split('<br/>')[-1]
print(text.replace('</td>','').strip())
```

With BS4 BeautifulSoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
soup_ = soup(html,'html.parser')
soup_ = soup_.find('td').text.split('\n')[-2]
```

Comment: what if the there is `\n` inside the text?

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe use a Regex for that specific task

You can Try the following code that worked for me (need to test some more cases):

```
import re

html="""    <td>
      ValueToBeDeleted
      <br>
      <br/> ValueToKeep
    </td>"""

value_search = re.search(r'\<br\/\>(.*)', html, re.IGNORECASE)

if value_search:
    value = title_search.group(1)

print(value)
```